# Can DPM 2007 back up Active Directory?

Tags: backup, active-directory, scdpm

We're installing Microsoft Data Protection Manager 2007 - we'll be using it to back up Exchange and SQL Server among other things.

Does anyone know if DPM can also back up Active Directory?

It sounds like the answer is "not really". You can install the DPM agent on a domain controller and make system state backups. But if your Active Directory is out of commission, there will be no way to restore the backups, since DPM depends on AD.

Currently we're just using Windows Backup (ntbackup) to take system state backups on one of the DCs. Should we just continue with that?

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, DPM enterprise licenses come with a license for a separate tool, DPMsrt (DPM system recovery tool) for bare metal restores (which if your AD is totaly dead you would have to do) see [Backup for Bare Metal Recovery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb795820.aspx).  Now if all you want is to restore a working AD to a previous state see  "[Introduction to Administering Active Directory Backup and Restore](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738755(WS.10).aspx)" and [Backup of Protected Computer System State](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb809015.aspx)